# Using next() in the parameter of if/else statement

Tags: java, iterator, java.util.scanner, dna-sequence

So I am pretty sure I am using next and hasNext incorrectly... I am attempting to input a string of ACGT characters and then count the individual resulting letters. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A1Novice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input = "";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner j = new Scanner(input);
        System.out.println("Enter nucleobases (enter end when done)");
        while(true){
            input = s.next() + input;
            if(s.next().contains("end")){
                break;
            }
        }
        process(j, input);  
    }

    public static void process(Scanner j, String input){
        int a = 0, c = 0, g = 0, t = 0;
        while(j.hasNext()){
            if (j.next()=="A"){
                a++;
            }
            else if(j.next()=="C"){
                c++;
            }
            else if(j.next()=="G"){
                g++;
            }
            else if(j.next()=="T"){
                t++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("A count: " + a);
                System.out.println("C count: " + c);
                System.out.println("G count: " + g);
                System.out.println("T count: " + t);
                break;
                }
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Yeah you want to use the .equals method

Comment: Cache the result of `j.next()` in some variable, then check for its value instead.

Comment: @DennisMeng Not a duplicate, but useful link.

Comment: also, yes, j.next() will remove an element so here you're removing 4 elements per loop just to see if they are equal

Comment: There is no need to use next() in the if check

Comment: How about `String tmp = j.next()`, then compare `tmp`.

Comment: @Darkhogg Ah yeah, I see the other issue here now. Granted, the problem he's going to hit *after* that *is* a dupe.

Comment: Thanks guys! So I am using the if/else solution with j.next() assigned to a variable and using the .equals method instead of ==. After I enter input the program still crashes, I ran debugging and there seems to be a problem with `String val = j.next();`... any ideas?

Comment: @DennisMeng What is the other issue you mentioned earlier?

Comment: I was referring to the string comparison, but it looks like you've got that part already. As for the crashing that you're getting now, `Scanner j = new Scanner(input)` is *definitely* not what you want. Go back over your `main`, there's still at least two issues I see.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand. Would System.In work better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already written you have to put your next element in a local variable.

This is not enough however: please never use `==` to compare strings. Use String's method `equals`instead or even `equalsIgnoreCase`.

You should use something like :

```
String val = j.next();
if(val.equals("A")){ // you could use val.equalsIgnoreCase("A") to be case insensitive
    ...
} else if (val.equals("B")){
    ...
```

As suggested in aljipa's answer, you you to use a switch. If you want your test to be case insensitive can can also write something like:

```
String val = j.next();
switch (val.toUpperCase()) {
    case "A":
        a++;
        break;
    case "B":
        ...
```

Comment: In Java 7, you can also use a switch statement instead.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to add it in anyway (so that your answer stands alone). Generally, what I do when I add extra info is acknowledge the person in the answer (since they *did* bring it up first).

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a local variable.

```
 String next = j.next();
```

and use that in your if statements. Otherwise you will advance the iterator in every check.

Here is what it should look like:

```
public static void process(Scanner j, String input){
    int a = 0, c = 0, g = 0, t = 0;

    while(j.hasNext()){
        String n = j.next();
        if (n.equals("A")){
            a++;
        }
        else if(n.equals("C")){
            c++;
        }
        else if(n.equals("G")){
            g++;
        }
        else if(n.equals("T")){
            t++;
        }
        else{
            ...
        }
     }

}
```

Plus, do not use == to compare Strings. The == operator will check if it is the same object instance, but not whether the content is equal. Use the `equals` method instead.

Comment: Using `==` to compare strings is a bad idea because you onlly compare references, not the value of the string itself!

Comment: yes you are right of course! didnt look at that. I edited my sample.

Answer (score 1):

k-mera's answer is correct, but consider using switch since it's asymptomatically more effective:

```
public static void process( Scanner j, String input ) {
 int a = 0, c = 0, g = 0, t = 0;
 String ch;
 while( j.hasNext() ) {
     switch( ch = j.next() ) {
         case "A":
              a++;
              break;
     case "C":
          c++;
          break;
     case "G":
          g++;
          break;
     case "T":
          t++;
          break;
         default:
              System.out.println("A count: " + a);
              System.out.println("C count: " + c);
              System.out.println("G count: " + g);
              System.out.println("T count: " + t);
              return;
         }
     }
}
```

Additionally I'd rather use simple ( char ) System.in.read() if you need to read char by char there's no need in polluting your heap with redundant String instances which is exactly what Scanner.next() does ***unless*** you don't  tokenise the input in a custom way.

Comment: No, as it was written k-mera's answer was not correct but yours is ... (only in Java 7 however)! Furthermore, it is more readable.

Comment: Uh, it seems he already edited and I didn't notice. I think readability is not as important as more asymptomatically faster algorithm, some would doubt that a switch with lots of breaks is more readable. As for Java 7, Scanner wasn't there until Java 5 too :)

Comment: I had put a comment on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The j.next() on an iterator will essentially go on to the next loop so you're making 4 loops on every loop.